# Is there a way to log SQLite queries?

Tags: php, sqlite

I am using prepared statements like:

```
$mysqlite = new SQLite3("test.sqlite", SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE);
$stmnt = $mysqlite->prepare("INSERT INTO Friends VALUES(?,?,?)");
$stmnt->bindValue(1,4,SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$stmnt->bindValue(2,"Jane",SQLITE3_TEXT);
$stmnt->bindValue(3,"F",SQLITE3_TEXT);
$stmnt->execute();
```

Is there a way to log queries when using prepared statements?

Edit:
What strategy would you suggest to debug queries, in case queries cannot be extracted from SQLite3 prepared statement?

Comment: If you are trying to log the statement with data, I think you are going to be disappointed.

Comment: Brad is right - the documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3stmt.php shows there is no method on preparedstatement that returns the finalized query to log.

Comment: Brad, msgmash.com: What alternate strategy would you suggest for debugging/logging queries?

Comment: @GaminGrounds: The link you shared discusses error logging in c/c++ language, whereas I am seeking a solution in PHP and I did search before posting question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extend `SQLite3` class and wrap the `SQLite3Stmt` object by overriding the `prepare` method. In your wrapper implement the `bindValue` and `execute` methods and call them on the `SQLite3Stmt` object (add logging here). To finish it off you could add the [magic](http://us.php.net/__get) `__get` and `__call` functions for any methods/properties you're not intercepting.

For this to work you have to change "new SQLite3" to "new SQLite3Debug" (assuming your extended class is called this).